# The term 'EHLO' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: windows, telnet, windows-server, smtp-server

I've installed and configured SMTP server on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. The installation and configuration was successful, to the best of my knowledge.

But I'm having issues with testing the SMTP server configuration by sending an email message using the SMTP server. I used telnet by running the following command:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

I get an error message, whenever I try to start communication with the server by running the following command:

```
EHLO server
```

As follows is the error message:

```
EHLO : The term 'EHLO' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ EHLO server
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EHLO:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That's a Powershell error. Looks like you are connecting to port 23, where Windows offers Powershell.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy, thanks for your response. How do I fix it, please?

Comment: Does anyone know hos to fix this PowerShell error? Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? For example, have you checked what listens on port 25? Also telnet is an ancient utility and I don't know if it works when you run it from powershell (as I assume you do). Maybe you're not interacting with the server at all. PS: this question is not really for StackOverflow because it's not about programming. Try ServerFault.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy, thanks for your continued assistance. I really don't know how to check what listens to port 25.

Comment: `netstat -nao`. And use /dev/hands generally.